# Filter list of values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to filter a number of fixed values (885,900,915,930,945), I can do it like this:

```
filteredData = data.options.filter(item => item.foo === 'CALL' && (item.bar === 885 || item.bar === 900 || item.bar === 915 || item.bar === 930 || item.bar === 945));
```

but it feels like an ugly solution. What I would like to do is is something like:

```
const barConst = 885 || 900 || 915 || 930 || 945;
filteredData = data.options.filter(item => item.foo === 'CALL' && (item.bar === barConst);
```

but that will obviously not work. Any slick way I can do this in Javascript/node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an array and check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
const
    barConst = [885, 900, 915, 930, 945],
    filteredData = data.options.filter(
        ({ foo, bar }) => foo === 'CALL' && barConst.includes(bar)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

`includes` only works in ES6, `indexOf` works in ES5 as well and you can achieve the same result:

```
const barConst = [885, 900, 915, 930, 945];

    filteredData = data.options.filter(item => 
           item.foo === 'CALL' && barConst.indexOf(item.bar) > 0);
```

https://www.codementor.io/adroitcoder/includes-vs-indexof-in-javascript-ivxhatb3y